# How to change the content of the layout?

Tags: java, android

In my Android application i have a tracker activity in which i retrieve the exercises information(name , period , burned calories) from the sqlite data base based on the selected date and display these information in a linear layout , and my problem that as the user select new date the retrieved data are displayed in another "new " layout appear above the old one but what actually i want to do is to display the new retrieved data on the same layout " change the layout content with the new retrieved data ", i have tried the remove all views method but it didn't work since the data appear for few minutes then dis appear

How i can do this: when the user select a new date the new retrieved data displayed on the same layout " refresh the old data by the new one " not to display them in anew layout . how i can do that ? please help me..

**java code**

```
public class Tracker extends BaseActivity
  {  
private Button date_btn;
private ImageButton  left_btn;
private ImageButton  right_btn;
private ImageView    nodata;
private TextView ex_name;
private TextView ex_BCals;

private LinearLayout  excercises_LL;
private LinearLayout content_LL ;
private LinearLayout  notes;
private LinearLayout  details;  
private int year,month,day;
private double  tot_excals_burned;
private Calendar  localCalendar; 
private static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID=0;
private  boolean  has_ex_details;
private boolean  has_meal_details=false;
private Cursor exercises_cursor;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.tracker);




    date_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
    date_btn.setText(FormatDate());
    date_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            year = localCalendar.get(1);
            month= localCalendar.get(2);
            day  =  localCalendar.get(5);
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });


    left_btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_left);
    left_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            localCalendar.add(5, -1);
            date_btn.setText(FormatDate(localCalendar,"EEEE, d/MMM/yyyy"));

            RefreshExercisesData();
            RefreshNoDataImage();
        }
    });

    right_btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_right) ;
    right_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            localCalendar.add(5, 1);
            date_btn.setText(FormatDate(localCalendar,"EEEE, d/MMM/yyyy"));

            RefreshExercisesData();
            RefreshNoDataImage();

        }
    });


    details=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_details);
    notes=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_notes);
    excercises_LL=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_exercises);
    nodata=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nodata_imgV);



    RefreshExercisesData();
    RefreshNoDataImage();


}


private String  FormatDate()
{   

    localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    return new  SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d/MMM/yyyy").format(localCalendar.getTime());

}

private String FormatDate(int year, int month, int day)
{   
    localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    localCalendar.set(year, month, day);

    return new  SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d/MMM/yyyy").format(localCalendar.getTime());
}

private String FormatDate(Calendar   calendar , String  format)
{

    return new  SimpleDateFormat(format).format(calendar.getTime());

}




private void RefreshExercisesData()
{   



    tot_excals_burned=0;

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    String selected_date= date_btn.getText().toString();
    Log.e("date", selected_date);


    exercises_cursor = db.getExerciseInfo(selected_date);

    if(exercises_cursor.getCount() !=0 )
    {

        has_ex_details=true;

        details.setVisibility(0);
        nodata.setVisibility(8);
        notes.setVisibility(0);

        //excercises_LL.removeAllViews();
        excercises_LL.setWeightSum(1.0F);
        excercises_LL.setVisibility(0);



        excercises_LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LayoutInflater exc_LayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)exc_LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tracker_header_item,null);
        TextView   tot_ex_cals_value=((TextView)(layout).findViewById(R.id.tv_tot_cals_value));
        TextView   exs_title=((TextView)(layout).findViewById(R.id.tv_item_title)) ;
        exs_title.setText("Exercises ");

        (layout).setPadding(0, 36, 0, 0);
        excercises_LL.addView((View)layout, 0);
        int i = 1;

        if (exercises_cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do 
            {
                content_LL=new LinearLayout(this);
                ex_name=new TextView(this);
                ex_name.setText( exercises_cursor.getFloat(1)+","  +exercises_cursor.getString(0) + "min ");
                ex_name.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                content_LL.addView(ex_name,0);

                ex_BCals=new TextView(this);
                ex_BCals.setText(Round(exercises_cursor.getFloat(2)) +" ");
                ex_BCals.setTextColor(R.color.color_black);
                content_LL.addView(ex_BCals,1);

                tot_excals_burned = tot_excals_burned+exercises_cursor.getFloat(2);

                excercises_LL.addView(content_LL, i);


                i++; 

            }
            while (exercises_cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        tot_ex_cals_value.setText(Round(tot_excals_burned) );

    }
    else if(exercises_cursor.getCount()==0 ||tot_excals_burned==0)
    {  

        has_ex_details=false;


        RefreshNoDataImage();

    }
    exercises_cursor.close();
    exercises_cursor.deactivate();
    db.close();

}


private void RefreshNoDataImage()
{    
    if(has_ex_details==false && has_meal_details==false)
    {       

        notes.setVisibility(8);
        excercises_LL.setVisibility(8);
        nodata.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_nodata);
        nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    else
        nodata.setVisibility(8);


}




protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, this.year, this.month, this.day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker paramDatePicker, int year, int monthofYear, int dayofMonth)
    {
        Tracker.this.year=year;
        month=monthofYear;
        day=dayofMonth;
        date_btn.setText(FormatDate(year,month,day));
        RefreshExercisesData();
        RefreshNoDataImage();

    }

};


private  String Round(double num) {
    return String.format("%.1f%n", num);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to edit your question, if you want us to see any code samples.

If this is only a few texts for an exercise, it should be sufficient to give those views ids in the layout xml, so they can be referenced in your activity.

Then you can just get your views with findViewById in OnCreate, and when you receive data for the new exercise, you update those views with e.g. TextView.setText().

Comment: thanks , i have tried what you said before i post my question and try this approach " create text views in the activity" and the problem still .
do you know another way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a layout, for example one like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calories_burned_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your Activity where you have access to your data from your sqlite db, you can modify the existing textviews within this layout by finding the view and using the setText method.

```
// load new data occurs above, now want to set
TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_textview);
name.setText(newName);

TextView calsBurned = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.calories_burned_textview);
calsBurned.setText(newCalsBurned);
```

It's possible, from what it sounds like in your description, that you are adding these textviews to the Activity via code each time some load button is clicked. You can do this, just hold on to the reference to these textviews you added and use setText() later on when you load a new entry (but don't create the textviews a second time).

Comment: Ihave similar problem , and i am using the same  approach that you say but the problem still the data appear for few minutes then its  dis appear

Comment: what about remove removeAllViews() method it will be used in this case ?